# How to expect the output from multiple commands

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I have a list of commands that I'm passing to an expect script. The list looks like this:

```
date && ls /
```

The expect script will have to wait and capture the output of every single command remotely run.

Currenlty just using:

```
send "$cmd\r"
expect -re "(.*)\r" {
    puts "expect_out(buffer)"
}
```

will print only the first command output.

How can I redesign the regex to capture the output of all commands? Even better: would it be possible to loop through the command outputs and printing them one after another?

Comment: That `expect` snippet is waiting for the first line of data and then printing and moving on. If you want it to wait for more you need to tell it to `expect` again. Look at the `expect` docs.

Comment: I had a look at the documentation and could not find anything related. Could you please be more specific on what I should look for?

Comment: In the man page in the section on the `expect` command. Look for `exp_continue`.